# Definite article before Noun+Name construction

Tags: articles

Would the following sentence be correct?

> Anna Müller of German website "Utopia.de" wrote that...

Or would I have to use an article?

> Anna Müller of *the* German website "Utopia.de" wrote that...

And if not, why?

Comment: Hello, Louis. Firstly, note that 'German' in your sentences is an adjective, not a noun. It is capitalised because it is a _proper adjective_ like 'British', 'Californian', and 'Parisian' in some sentences. Yes, they can be nouns, but not when used before a head noun ('British airmen', 'Californian raisins', 'German website'.  Secondly, it's a little unusual to label someone as being 'of a particular website'. They're usually users of, contributors to, visitors to a website. Thirdly, using an article in 'Anna Müller, a contributor to [the] German website "Utopia.de" is common but optional.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm having trouble creating a sound answer here. Maybe you can help? I started to answer that the article is not needed because "website" is an appositive. But 1) it's the proper noun Utopia.de that would be the appositive anyway, and 2) I can't find a source to support the idea that you don't need an article in "bla bla [general-noun-as-adjectival] [specific noun]." All I can find is a lot of vague talk about titles... but I guess the point is that this stunt only works when the specific noun is in fact a proper noun? Maybe you could provide a more coherent answer.

Comment: I'm not sure where the lines are myself.  Certainly 'Ann Miller writing in hilarious periodical "Shangri.der" wrote that ...' is unacceptable. I'm guessing it's to do with the classifier ... identifier ... descriptor roles of premodifiers. 'Hilarious' is a descriptor, far from identificational/classifying. The need for the definite article seeps through.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Maybe I should start a question. My train of thought was: we keep hearing about "titles." And yes, that would seem to explain "The Bears traded star quarterback Meathead McMuscley"—"quarterback" is a title. But what about cases in which it's more a descriptor than anything that could be called a title? "The crime was witnessed by restaurateur Tony Vincenzo," "... by cabbie Bob Lefkowicz," "by local vagrant Billy Smith."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, do you have any examples that are not people? "I am going to London" is fine, as is "I am going to the English capital, London", but "I am going to English capital London" isn't. Is there a form of this that allows "the" to be left out?

Comment: @Peter I'm not unhappy with 'which is home to World War II Aircraft Carrier _Yorktown_ 
 which I've found online, though without the premodifier 'World War II' I think it's at best borderline.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer would be that you need *the* here because it is *the website*. You could use

> Anna Müller of "Utopia.de" wrote that ...

because *Utopia.de* is a name.

You can see from the comments there are similar constructions where using *the* is optional, and the rules are not always clear. Even if *the* is optional it is still correct to add it, and my recommendation would be that you do so.

Comment: Adding the identifying modifier before 'website' licenses the anarthrous usage. While the definite article is arguably necessary in 'He wrote a biography of the composer C P E Bach', it becomes optional in 'There is a statue of German composer George Frederick Handel in Vauxhall Gardens'.

Comment: Also optional in "The orchestra accompanied flautist Fred Smith". But where is the line? Is it that "flautist" can be considered a title?